Integrate Python Model to Power Bi
In power BI  I have to create a NLP based chatbot kind of thing, like we have QnA visual in power bi which can answer the question asked in Natural Language Processing but it due to some of it's limitations I can't use.
I want to train my dataset using python and create a model which can answer any question asked in natural language.
However the problem is I can't run python script into Power bi , since there is no gateway connection for it so it will not refresh, I do not have to do in my local system only it should be reached out to end user. Anything if I load into power bi will eventually look like a table  and I have to create a visual of it.
I want to know in what ways it could be possible to use the QnA model written in python to inculcate the python model into power bi, so that a user can go search about the question they want to ask in a  natural language.
Is there a way to use python so that the end user can type their question and get their answer like a chat bot?
